# How to get all child process's PIDs when given the parent PID in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, parent-child

I know that this can be done in bash by: `pstree parent-pid`. But how can I do this `in C`? Is there any method that doesn't have to iterating the whole /proc file system (e.g. system call/library function)?

Comment: pstree is written in C. Why don't you just look at the source code for it? https://gitorious.org/busybox/busybox/source/1c7a58dfb82ea04c525e0c19f94f2d800dee99e3:procps/pstree.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `popen` to read the output of the command `ps -ef`,then look for the all the child process of a specified `PID`

```
int getAllChildProcess(pid_t ppid)
{
   char *buff = NULL;
   size_t len = 255;
   char command[256] = {0};

   sprintf(command,"ps -ef|awk '$3==%u {print $2}'",ppid);
   FILE *fp = (FILE*)popen(command,"r");
   while(getline(&buff,&len,fp) >= 0)
   {
     printf("%s\n",buff);
   }
   free(buff);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `ps -ef|awk '$3==parent-pid {print $2}'` command,every line of the output of the cmd is the childprocess pid,so you can read the output by `popen`

Comment: This trick actually still uses linux shell tools which I don't want to involve. Because this may be time-consuming job comparing to the situation inside my program. It looks like there is no convenient syscall/libcall to solve this

Comment: But `pstree` also call `ps` command.if you won't call 'ps',you must write a `kenerl module`

Answer (score 0):

@sundq 's answer is right, but have a bug.

The file descriptor from popen() must be closed with `pclose()` rather than `fclose`. So, just replace `fclose(fp);` with `pclose(fp);`.

reference:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html