# How to find all child process of a parent process (in C)

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, parallel-processing

I have to create a Process family as shown in picture, which I did.
The next step is to print for all Parent Processes, that they are waiting for their X Childs.

My problem now is how do i figure out or get the information of how many children a parent process has.

We are programming with language C on the Debian Shell, if you could consider this, while giving your answer that would be nice.

I didn't write my code down here on purpose, because I don't want to get code-based answers but ideas and tipps with arguments like a while for a loop... I hope you understand what I mean ^^

Thanks in advance.

[image: How the process family looks alike. Picture!]

Comment: Looks like a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393397/how-to-get-all-child-processs-pids-when-given-the-parent-pid-in-c

Comment: no i don't want code but hints and tipps ... also we haven't had pointers in C yet ... i guess those stars are pointers ....

Comment: it's hard to come up with an answer if you start ruling them out based on what "you already had" in your course (at least for anybody who is not attending the course)

Comment: You really can't get far in C without using pointers. I don't think you should be required to do anything more advanced than adding integers without getting to know them to be honest... definitely not messing with Linux internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following would be very basic steps you would like to do:

PS: Assuming you have not completed recursive function calls yet.

```
STEP1: First get the process id PID
STEP2:Find the child process IDs for PID and maintain a list (array) of them.
STEP3:Repeat STEP2 for all child process IDs saved in the list
```